# Matching two pairs of columns with one common value in Google Sheets to list discrepancies

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I have a Google Sheets spreadsheet with two sets of data, both centered around individuals' names. I want to compare the two datasets and get a list of the differences.

So, if a name in column E also appears in column J, then I want it to start the comparison. For the name in column E, I want to look at the value in column G. For the name in column J, I want it to look at the value in column L. If the values in columns G and L aren't the same, I want it to add the name from column E, then the values in columns G and L, to a list.

The catch is that the two lists aren't the same length, with some names on one list but not the other, and the same names won't appear in the same order, either. **I can change the order of the columns if having each pair be adjacent would be required for this to work.**

Here's a screenshot of what I *want* to achieve:
[image: sample spreadsheet]

The most important part to me is that it list the entries in green (where the same name is in columns E and J, but different values in G and L). I'd also *like* to see it list the names that appear in column E, but not column J, but that's not essential; that's the part in blue. If I lived in a perfect world, it would also pull in the entries that have entries in column J, but not column E (in red), but I suspect that can't be done in a single formula.

I know that finding the names in one column, but not the other, would start with a FILTER command, something like:

=FILTER(E2:E,COUNTIF(J2:J,E2:E)=0)
and
=FILTER(J2:J,COUNTIF(E2:E,J2:J)=0)

What I don't know is how to bring the second (and third) columns along for the ride, particularly since those values won't be in the same row.

Answer (score 0):

can you try out this formula in cell A2:

`=QUERY(MAP(BYROW(UNIQUE({E2:E;J2:J}),LAMBDA(ax,ax)),BYROW(UNIQUE({E2:E;J2:J}),LAMBDA(ax,XLOOKUP(ax,E:E,G:G,))),BYROW(UNIQUE({E2:E;J2:J}),LAMBDA(ax,XLOOKUP(ax,J:J,L:L,))),LAMBDA(ax,bx,cx,IF(ax="",,IF(bx=cx,,{ax,bx,cx,COUNTA({ax,bx,cx})})))),"Select Col1, Col2, Col3 Where Col1!='' ORDER BY Col4 dESC")`

-

[image]